# how to use the switch / toggle in remoteviews layout?

Tags: android, toggle, switch-statement

I want to use switch(view) or toggle(view) in removteviews, but it will get a RemoteServiceException when I put  in layout.xml.

In android development webpage([appwidgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)), the switch/toggle are not in the supported lists.

So, how can I use the switch/toggle in remoteview layout?

Comment: ... you can't because it's not supported? ...

Comment: I mean, I want to use switch button in remoteviews layout, but 
<Switch 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
will throw RemoteServiceException when I executing my activity.

Is Switch button not supported in remoteviews layout, even in jelly beam? Try to use a Button or ImageButton is only solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: *"Is Switch button not supported in remoteviews layout, even in jelly beam? Try to use a Button or ImageButton is only solution?"* - Yes and yes. RemoteViews are limited by design (for security reasons I believe), so not every new view will get thrown in there. You can't use the switch control in a remoteview layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. You can try to use a `Button` or `ImageButton`, where you adjust the contents of the face of the button to represent a "toggled" state, as those are supported by app widgets. No subclass of `CompoundButton` is supported, probably because there is no way to read the value of the button from the app widget.